# Cannot install virt-manager, python dependencies

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, python, libvirt

I have a debian 11 machine, I installed KVM on it, and I would like to also install virt-manager, but I got :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3-libxml2 : Depends: libpython3.7 (>= 3.7.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And when I try to install libpython3.7 I got this :

```
Package libpython3.7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'libpython3.7' has no installation candidate
```

What is strange, is I already have uptodate python 3 :

```
python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
```

Could anyone give me some help please ?

Many thanks